# How to pass array list object from one class to other class in android

Tags: android

My code in one class is

```
ArrayList<String> categoryList=new ArrayList<String>();

    // Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, listview.class);
    // mIntent.putExtra("nameOfArray",categoryList);

    // startActivity(mIntent);

       for(int i=0;i<docmntElmnt.getPropertyCount();i++)
       {

        SoapObject table = (SoapObject)docmntElmnt.getProperty(i);
        categoryList.add(table.getProperty("Nombre").toString());
        //categoryList.add(table.getProperty("Imagen1").toString());

       }
       Log.d(TAG,"Name and image of soap response is"+categoryList );
```

I want to pass array list object "categorylist" to other class in second class I have to get these values and i wnt to display thes values to listview

Please any one help me

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an `ArrayList` as an Extra to an Intent using `putStringArrayListExtra (String name, ArrayList<String> value)`. [See here for the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putStringArrayListExtra%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.ArrayList%3Cjava.lang.String%3E%29).